Finding the Top X Coordinate Points that Capture the Most Store Locations within a X Mile Radius
I have a list of 500 stores and their latitude and longitude coordinates. I'm trying to find the 30 unique coordinate points that capture the highest number of "Constrained" stores within a 15 mile radius without any overlap and minimizing the average distance from the center point to the stores.
My approach has been to create a grid of latitude-longitude grid, and test every point in Python, but it seems to be way to slow of an approach. All stores are in the US.
Here's my code:
# Define the 15-mile radius in kilometers
RADIUS_KM = 15 * 1.60934

# Define a grid with a given range of latitudes and longitudes
def generate_grid(lat_range, lon_range, lat_step, lon_step):
    latitudes = np.arange(lat_range[0], lat_range[1], lat_step)
    longitudes = np.arange(lon_range[0], lon_range[1], lon_step)
    return [(lat, lon) for lat, lon in product(latitudes, longitudes)]

def calculate_distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    return geodesic((lat1, lon1), (lat2, lon2)).km

# Create a grid of candidate points (this is for Texas as an example)
lat_range = (25.83, 43)  
lon_range = (-106.6466, -93.5072)  
lat_step = .05
lon_step = .05

grid = generate_grid(lat_range, lon_range, lat_step, lon_step)

# Create a list to store results for each grid point
results = []

for point in grid:
    constrained_distances = []
    for index, row in Texas.iterrows():
        distance = calculate_distance(point[0], point[1], row['Latitude'], row['Longitude'])
        if distance <= RADIUS_KM and row['Constraint Check'] == 'Constrained':
            constrained_distances.append(distance)
    
    constrained_count = len(constrained_distances)
    average_distance = np.mean(constrained_distances) if constrained_distances else float('inf')
    
    results.append({
        'Location': point,
        'Constrained Count': constrained_count,
        'Average Distance': average_distance
    })


That's only 100,000 points, which is not outrageous.  You might consider using a simple distance calculation instead of the geodesic one ((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2) -- over those short distances, it won't make a difference.  And I don't know what you mean by "without any overlap".  Your grid points are 3 miles apart, so there's going to be overlap.

Thanks, by overlap I guess I meant I want to exclude points with a 15 mile radius that include the same stores (for example, if Point A with 15 mile radius includes stores 1 and 2 and the avg. distance is 10 miles, I want to discard Point B with 15 mile radius that also includes stores A and B but with a larger avg. distance. Maybe discarding those points can be done after, however)

I was starting to construct an analytical solution to this.  This doesn't answer the question, and as such should earn me downvotes, but perhaps this can help you visualize the problem here.
What I've done is created a grid of points 3 miles apart.  I generate 500 random stores across the grid.  I then create an array that is a circle 15 miles in radius (which is 5 grid points).  For each store, I then add that circle into the big master grid.  After that, the value of the grid array is "how many stores are within 15 miles of me?".
import random
import numpy as np

# Create a grid of candidate points (this is for Texas as an example)
lat_range = (25.83, 43)  
lon_range = (-106.6466, -93.5072)  
lat_step = .05
lon_step = .05

stepsx = int(abs((lat_range[1]-lat_range[0]) / lat_step))
stepsy = int(abs((lon_range[1]-lon_range[0]) / lon_step))

def x2lat(x):
    return lat_range[0]+x*lat_step

def y2lon(y):
    return lon_range[0]+y*lon_step

def generate_random_stores():
    stores = []
    for i in range(500):
        x = x2lat(random.random() * stepsx)
        y = y2lon(random.random() * stepsy)
        stores.append((x,y))
    return stores

stores = generate_random_stores()

# Define a 15 mile radius circle.

R=5
R2=R+R+1
R4=R2+R2

circle = np.zeros((R2,R2))
for x in range(-R,R+1):
    for y in range(-R,R+1):
        circle[x+R,y+R] = x*x+y*y <= R*R

# Define a complete grid with a border, so we don't have to clip the edges.

grid = np.zeros( (stepsx+R4,stepsx+R4) )

# Add circles around all of the stores.

for lat,lon in stores:
    x = int((lat-lat_range[0]) / lat_step)
    y = int((lon-lon_range[0]) / lon_step)
    grid[x+R2:x+R4,y+R2:y+R4] += circle

largest = int(grid.max())

for n in range(3):
    cur = largest - n
    print("These points have",cur,"stores within 15 miles:")
    for x,y in np.argwhere(grid==cur):
        print("%.2f %.2f" % (x2lat(x-31),y2lon(y-31)))

Example output:
These points have 5 stores within 15 miles:
40.63 -103.80
These points have 4 stores within 15 miles:
26.68 -104.30
26.68 -103.20
26.68 -103.15
26.73 -104.45
26.73 -104.40
26.73 -104.35
26.73 -104.30
26.73 -104.25
26.73 -104.20
26.78 -104.45
26.78 -104.40
26.78 -104.35
26.78 -104.30
26.78 -104.25
26.83 -104.40
26.93 -104.40
27.73 -103.70
33.28 -102.90
37.28 -97.35
37.33 -97.40
37.33 -97.35
37.38 -97.40
37.38 -97.35
37.43 -97.40
37.43 -97.35
37.48 -97.45
... etc ...

FOLLOOWUP
This code lets you see the map grid, kind of like a heat map:
def plot(grid):
    mapx = []
    for row in grid:
        mapx.append( ''.join('.123456789'[int(c)] for c in row))
    return '\n'.join(mapx)

print(plot(grid))

Partial output:
......................11..............11111112222223111111..
.....................................1111111221121111.2.....
.....................................111111122111112212111..
.....................................1111111221111233222221.
....................................11111112222111333322222.
................1....................1111111221111333222222.
.............1111111.................11111112211123332222221
............112111111................11111112211123332222221
...........1322222111.................111111111111332222222.
.........122333322211....................1......1.222222222.
........11233333322111............................122222221.
........1122333332211...............1..............1112111..
........1222333332221............1111111..............1.....
.......11122333333211...........111111111...................
........112223333221............111111111...................
........11222222311.............111111111...................
........1112222221.............11111111111..................
.........1111121................111111111...................
.....1......1...................111111111...................
..1111111.......................111111111...................
.111111111.......................1111211....................
.111111111..1.....................1121111...................
.111111112111111.................1111111111.................
11111111222111111................1111112221111..............
.1111111221111111................11111222211111.............
.1111111221111111...............111111222221111.............
.11111122211111111...............11111222211111.............
..111111211111111................111122222111111............
.....1..111111111................11111222211111.............
........111111111.................1111222111111.............
.........1111111.....................1111111111..........111
............1..........................1111111..........1111
..........................................1.............1111

